# Google broke Sheets Query Importrange functionality: "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col1"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A weird behaviour is suddenly affecting a Google Sheets formula, which used to work until a couple days ago, is now throwing

> "Error Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
> NO_COLUMN: Col1

Offending formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/##id-here##/"; "#Students!D2:Q");"Select Col1" )
```

Notice that, when using the following syntax (`Select *` in place of `Select Col1`), a data set which includes multiple columns is correctly loaded into the sheet:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/##id-here##/"; "#Students!D2:Q");"Select *" )
```

**EDIT**

It looks like enclosing the whole `IMPORTRANGE` statement into brackets `{}` will fix the issue. I will leave the question unanswered to see if someone can explain this behaviour and why this suddenly changed.... Thanks Google for the update :-(

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/##id-here##/"; "#Students!D2:Q")};"Select Col1" )
```

All formulas in use, required this update. Thanks to ChatGPT, I could easily fix this with the following Google Apps Script:

```
function encloseImportRangeFormulasInBrackets() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var formulas = range.getFormulas();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < formulas[i].length; j++) {
        var formula = formulas[i][j];
        var updatedFormula = formula.replace(/(IMPORTRANGE\([^)]*\))/g, '{$1}');
        if (formula !== updatedFormula) {
          range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setFormula(updatedFormula);
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```